# How do I use python scripting to communicate with a Keysight/Agilent Network analyzer

Tags: python, gpib, network-analysis

I have downloaded the pyivi.0.08 package but experience an error when run the command import pyivi. I have also installed the NI Visa and the 488.2 package.
Is there any other package to be installed before running this command.

I am trying to communicate with a Keysight/Agilent Network analyzer through a GPIB using python scripting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error message did you receive?

Answer (score 0):

The package `pyivi.0.08` is supported on the Python package index and has a nice set of documentation here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyivi/0.0.8

If the documentation doesn't get you started, please list the specific error, and mention how far you were able to work through the documentation. I'll update my answer to respond to your error message.

Comment: it seems that it's last update was two years ago. is there any successive development on that? or create new project instead.